# how to create groups for woocommerce attribute products?

Tags: php, woocommerce

my problem is .. in woocommerce you have to list all attribute in one group .
for example i have some attribute like these :

**General Info**

Country : "something"
Material : "something"
Weight : "something"

**Display :**

Resolution : "something"
Colors : "something",

see. i want to put attributes in separate groups . ? is it possible ?

Comment: What is the derired result? I don't know what you mean. How do you mean in serperate groups? You just made seperate groups right...??

Comment: @Refilon  i mean make attributes separate by groups . for example : for camera product we have display information attributes, and lens information attributes.  and i want to show them separately

Comment: Can't you just add multiple attributes to the product..?? You also have an option to create subattributes in WooCommerce..

Comment: @Refilon really  ? where can i add sub attributes ?

Comment: If you go to an attribute, and then click on it. There you can make attributes. But you can also say that an attribute is a child of an other attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still searching: there is a [plugin for WooCommerce, that groups attributes](https://plugins.db-dzine.com/woocommerce-group-attributes/).

This also provides 3 styles as you can see in the Demo. You can order the attributes inside a group and load them in the admin panel - may give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with WooCommerce itself. You need a plugin for that. For example: https://wupoplugins.com/wupo-group-attributes-pro/

DISCLAIMER: I am the creator of that plugin

Comment: Please provide explanation to your answer instead of just a link.